# Updating the client view in Meteor js after a database insertion

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, meteor, reactive-programming

### First off, some background

My client has a kind of a "split-view", meaning- a *side-panel* displaying a list of objects and a *main view* displaying the *selected* object's details. Every time the user clicks on an Object in the list, a Backbone's route is called to navigate to the id which updates a **"selected"** property on the *Session*, what causes the *main view* to update- pretty standard stuff.

### The problem

I want the client to be as responsive as possible, therefore i'm trying to utilize Meteor's abillity to update the client immediately without waiting for a server confirmation.

My goal is that every time an Object is created, the *list* and the *main view* will be instantly updated to reflect the newly added Object. To achieve this I created a Meteor.method, *create()*, that uses Collection.insert and returns the id so I can use it with my Route. The method is shared across the client and server and is being called from within a **template's** event handler.

My first try was to store the returned id in a variable in the event handler and update the *Route* in the next line; For some reason, that didn't work because the method returned an **undefined** value. So I tried a different approach, instead of returning the id, I used it within the method to update the *Route* directly (if Meteor.isClient of course). That didn't work either because the id returned by Collection.insert in the client's version of the method was different from the one in the server's version.

#### First approach

```
Template.createDialog.events({
    'click #btn-dialog-create': function (event, template) {
        var objectId = Meteor.call('create');
        appRouter.navigate("object/id/" + objectId, {trigger:true});
    }
});
```

#### Second approach

```
Meteor.methods({
    create: function () {
        var ObjectId = Objects.insert({name:'test'});
        if(Meteor.isClient){
            appRouter.navigate("object/id/" + objectId, {trigger:true});
        }
    }
});
```

If anyone knows what's going on and can give me some directions that would be great.
Any different approaches to the problem or suggestions would be much appreciated as well.

Thanks

### Update

So I tried @Pent's suggestion and I got the same result as with my second approach. For some odd reason Meteor decides to *ignore* my id (created with *Random.id()*) and inserts the object with a different one.

So I tried another approach, I used just a simple string value instead of Random.id() and voila - **it worked.** Riddle me that.

Comment: I might help to share code for template helper displaying data, subscription function, and publish function.  Its not obvious from the above why client wouldn't update immediately. As answer below says your Meteor.method should not be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer for this question is defining a client side method that's responsible for creating the unique id (preferably using *Random.id()* ) and calling the Meteor.methods' *create()*. That way, you can have the id available immediately without waiting for the server to generate one. The trick here is to generate the id **outside** of the Meteor.method so that the id generation happens only once for both the stub and the actual server method.

```
create = function(){
    var id = Random.id();
    Meteor.call('create', id);
    return id;
}

Meteor.methods({
    create: function (id) {
        Objects.insert({_id: id, name:'test'});

        //more code...
    }
});


//and in the Template...
Template.createDialog.events({
    'click #btn-dialog-create': function (event, template) {
        var objectId = create();
        appRouter.navigate("object/id/" + objectId, {trigger:true});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer updated:

This will be both a client and server method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    create: function () {
        var id = Random.id();
        Objects.insert({_id: id, name:'test'});
        if(this.isSimulation) {
            appRouter.navigate("object/id/" + id, {trigger:true});
        }
    }
});
```

You can view a similar pattern from Meteor's party example: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/b28c81724101f84547c6c6b9c203353f2e05fbb7/examples/parties/model.js#L56

Comment: Thanks but the problem isn't the list not being updated with the new Object; It's the Router not navigating and displaying the the details in the main view

Comment: I've updated the answer to highlight a call with a traditional callback (error, result)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to use a traditional callback, I want the data to be available straight away for the user because the insertion operation is more likely to succeed. Only in case of a failure on the server, it will remove the new object and return to the previous state.

Comment: In that case you'll want the Meteor.method('create') available on both the client and the server. However you probably should use this.isSimulation and not Meteor.isClient

Comment: Thinking about it further, you might have to generate the id yourself using Random.id()

Comment: This is a good idea. Thanks! I wonder if it is best practice. I've noticed that if I create a normal method (not a Meteor.methods) it does return the correct id.

Comment: You might be able to use upsert in this case, but I feel like you should be able to specify an object ID on insert (looking at the source it doesn't look possible right now)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coused by the fact that remote methods, i.e. those which will be called on the server, don't simply return any value. Instead, they accept a callback that will be used to process the returned value (see [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call)). So in your first example you should probably do something like this:

```
Template.createDialog.events({
    'click #btn-dialog-create': function (event, template) {
        Meteor.call('create', function (error, result) {
            if (!error)
                appRouter.navigate("object/id/" + result, {trigger:true});
        });
    }
});
```

You also said:

> I want the client to be as responsive as possible, therefore i'm trying to utilize Meteor's abillity to update the client immediately without waiting for a server confirmation.

I think that in this case you should definitely wait for server response. Note, that there is no chance you get the correct object `id` unless this is given to you by the server.

One possible way to get around this issue is to create a local (client-side) collection:

```
// only on client
var temporary = new Meteor.Collection(null); // null name
```

in which you could store your "temporary" newly created objects, and then save them to the "real" collection after the user clicks the `save` button. You could implement your router to respond to urls like `object/new/*` to get access to these objects before they're saved to your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is *not* accurate. Meteor has a client version of the database by **default**, for every collection you create. In theory what **I want is to insert the object on the client and only if there was an error, which is unlikely in my case, I want to pull that object back.** That feature is a huge part of Meteor. If you're working with Meteor the way you described, as with any traditional webapp, you're missing out...

Comment: Maybe I was not very accurate, but also you misunderstood the technique I was describing. Imagine a situation in which two users are editing the same document. If you let Meteor update everything reactively, one of the users will probably loose all of his work as soon as the other one submits his results. That's where additional caching collections (client-side only) become handy. I'm not telling this is the only possible solution, but I'm quite sure this is a natural one. Also, it may not fit your requirements, but I can assure you that I'm not "missing out" here ;)

Comment: **BTW** If you don't like the `caching` technique, then the first part of my answer is exactly what you're looking for. Have you tried it?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. Again, the collections *are* available to the client by default because of the client's MongoDB version. This is Meteor's **latency compensation** feature. I'm not reinventing the wheel I just can't get it to work through Meteor.call. Thanks anyway for your suggestions!